# Image exported from GEE is pixelated when open in ArcMap

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, landsat-8, landsat-7

I am in my final step of exporting filtered images from Google Earth Engine.
Exporting params like so `// batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(roilist_0_g_2016_2020_col, 'Landsat07', {scale: 30});`

**Problem:** But the resulted image exported seems pixelated when open in ArcMap or not as clear as shown in the GEE Map view shown below the code edit.

**Image:** same tiff opened in ArcMap

[image: same tiff opened in ArcMap]

same tiff projected from Map.addLayer function in GEE[image: same tiff Map.addLayer]

Code:

```
// import 12 points coordinates csv file
var nesttest = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-sihaochen/assets/NESTTEST");

// create bufferPoints function
 function bufferPoints(radius, bounds) {
   return function(pt) {
     pt = ee.Feature(pt);
     return bounds ? pt.buffer(radius).bounds() : pt.buffer(radius);
   };
 }

// create 500m buffers for each point
var roi = nesttest.map(bufferPoints(500, false));
print(roi.size(), "roi size");
print(roi.getInfo());

// feature collection to List
var roigeometrylistfeature = roi.toList(roi.size());
print(roigeometrylistfeature, 'featurecollection to list');
// get first-index item in a list and conver to geometry
var roilist_0 = ee.Feature(roigeometrylistfeature.get(0));
var roilist_0_g = roilist_0.geometry();
print(roilist_0, roilist_0_g);

var start_year = 2016;
var end_year = 2020;
var years = ee.List.sequence(start_year, end_year);

function best_image_each_year (year){
  var start_date = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 01, 01);
  var end_date = start_date.advance(1, 'year');
  var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_TOA")
              .filterBounds(roilist_0_g)
              .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
              .select(['B3', 'B2', 'B1'])
              .sort("CLOUD_COVER")
              .first()
              .clip(roilist_0_g);
  return image;
}

var roilist_0_g_2016_2020 = years.map(best_image_each_year);
var roilist_0_g_2016_2020_col = ee.FeatureCollection(roilist_0_g_2016_2020);
// print(roilist_0_g_2016_2020.getInfo());
var roi_map = ee.Image(roilist_0_g_2016_2020.get(0));
print(roi_map.getInfo());

var trueColor321Vis = { 
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.4,
  gamma: 1.2,
};

Map.centerObject(roi_map, 14); 
Map.addLayer(roi_map, trueColor321Vis, 'True Color (321)');

var projection = roi_map.select('B2').projection().getInfo();
print(projection);

//\\ Exporting data
// batch download https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Batch; https://code.earthengine.google.com/dcee89acbe86bca49ce72605a9f5a7fe;
// https://code.earthengine.google.com/15f748dffa93c031eac646e449981d9d

// var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(roilist_0_g_2016_2020_col, 'Landsat07', {scale: 30});
```

GEE link [https://code.earthengine.google.com/b1aa2b0c0f530931205dea7ea5a7b208]

Does anyone know how to make the exported tiff image from GEE not looking so pixelated?

Comment: Looking at both images they seem to have the same resolution, the only difference would be your visualization parameters, probably to do with min/max values

Comment: Hi @M.Nicolas, thank you. I agree in hindsight it is the same resolution in gee and GIS. BUT you pointed out a good direction that to improve visualization parameters? Would you please give more insights on min/max values? I am very new to remote sensing, what can I search for to solve this problem?

Comment: I have not used ArcGIS in a while so I don't exactly remember how to tune the vis parameters on an RGB image, but I believe there are many resources online to that effect, such as this one https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/projects/color-management-application-settings.htm. Overall you want the params you used in GEE (trueColor321Vis) to match what you use in ArcGIS.